# Remix Arc Sandbox - handler is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, automatic-ref-counting, remix

Tried running Remix app in Arc sandbox via this command: `node ./dev sandbox` after doing `npx remix build`.
It starts a sandbox in port 3001 when accessed in the browser it throws this error:

```
Lambda error
Error: TypeError: handler is not a function
Lambda: @http any /*

: handler is not a function

Stack trace:
TypeError: handler is not a function,    at run ([eval]:1:6752),    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5),    at main ([eval]:1:6967)
```

I tried starting a fresh Remix app and the sandbox runs without any issues.

arc settings:

```
@app
remix-latest-7073

@http
/*
  method any
  src server

@static

@tables
user
  pk *String

password
  pk *String # userId

note
  pk *String  # userId
  sk **String # noteId
```

Tried deleting node_modules, and `server` directory, then running build command before sandbox.
Also tried pointing out the http resource to other folder but it just returns a different error.

I'm expecting the sandbox to run without any issues similar to when running arc sandbox on a freshly installed remix project.